# elasticsearch get all possible facets

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

is there a way to get the "top 10" facets but at the same time get all the possible facets we could have created (in that case, **all distinct kingdoms** in our document).

I know I could increase the "size" to a very big number, but then it generates a very big JSON and processing costs may be much bigger.

A simple facet...

```
"facets" : {
    "kingdom": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "kingdom",
            "size": 10
        } 
    }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: How can you get all the potential entries without receiving a big JSON back? Could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: i mean, i don't want to get something like
 {term:kingdom1, count:100}
for each possible facet (kingdom). This would be the big JSON I told you.

I just want the first ten 'kingdoms' (the more 'popular'), with its name and counts, but get also some info about how many possible facets I could have generated.
In SQL it sould be something like 'select count(distinct(kingdom)) from...'

Answer (score 0):

the size of the json response is proportional to the amount of different values you have for that term.

with that being said i believe what you want is to apply a sort

```
"sort":[{"kingdom":{"order":"desc"}}],"size":10
```

there will be two queries, the 
`"facets" :{"kingdom":{"terms":{"field": "kingdom","size": 10}}`
will return you all of the terms and the other query will return the first 10 order descending inside the "hits" field